# Lotus Script Agent unable to set the Cache HTTP headers

Tags: http-headers, lotus-domino, cache-control, lotusscript

This is on Domino 9.0.1 with IHS, my Lotus Script agent outputs an HTTP response, starting with the headers, an empty line, then body content..

If I output some custom header, such as `X-My-Header: Data`, it is output properly to the client.

However, Domino (HTTP Task) seems to completely discard my attempts to output any of the headers: `Cache-Control`, `Expires`.

The values would be overwritten as:

`Cache-Control: public
Expires: [almost one year from response time]`

and everybody happily caches a result which I don't want it to be cached.

This behaviour is persistent. I tried using a headers rule document to adjust the values but it only seems to work when the response Status Code is not 200 (OK). When the Status is 200, the headers rule is completely ineffective.

How can I set the Cache-Control and Expires headers? Have you been successful doing this? Do you use a different version of Domino?

Comment: I wrote a guide based on rules: www.experts-exchange.com/articles/5063/How-to-Leverage-browser-caching-on-a-lotus-Domino-Server-SEO-Domino.html. I many times had to restart the http task to get the rules to work.

Comment: I've actually came across your article while searching before posting here.

No matter what I try, when the response code is 200, these headers are overwritten.

Of course, I always restart the http task after every change, and have the the browser cache disabled.

Comment: Can you test it in a configuration without IHS?

Comment: @RichardSchwartz, I've just tested with & without IHS and found the same behaviour exactly.

Comment: I'm currently resorting to using response code 201 (Created) or 202 (Accepted) (depending on the case) to be able to output these headers.

Comment: Very strange, on my production web server it works. in my case I wanted to set a longer cach.  It seems obvious but did you select override application's header?